# Using sed/awk to limit/parse output of LDAP DN's

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I have a large list of LDAP DN's that are all related in that they failed to import into my application.  I need to query these against my back-end database based on a very specific portion of the CN, but I'm not entirely sure on how I can restrict down the strings to a very specific value that is not necessarily located in the same position every time.

Using the following bash command:

```
grep 'Failed to process entry' /var/log/tomcat6/catalina.out | awk '{print substr($0, index($0,$14))}'
```

I am able to return a list of DN's similar to: (sorry for the redacted nature, security dictates)

```
"cn=[Last Name] [Optional Middle Initial or Suffix] [First Name] [User name],ou=[value],ou=[value],o=[value],c=[value]".
```

The CN value can be confusing as the order of surname, given name, middle initial, prefix or suffix can be displayed in any order if the values even exist, but one thing does remain consistent, the username is always the last field in the cn (followed by a "," then the first of many potential OU's). I need to parse out that user name for querying, preferably into a comma separated list for easy copy and paste for use in a SQL IN() query or use in a bash script.  So as an example, imagine the following short list of abbreviated DNs, only showing the CN value (since the rest of the DN is irrelevant):

```
"cn=Doe Jr. John john.doe,ou=...".
"cn=Doe A. Jane jane.a.doe,ou=...".
"cn=Smith Bob J bsmith,ou=...".
"cn=Powers Richard richard.powers1,ou=...".
```

I would like to have a csv list returned that looks like:

```
john.doe,jane.a.doe,bsmith,richard.powers1
```

Can a mix of awk and/or sed accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -e 's/"^[^,]* \([^ ,]*\),.*/\1/'
```

will parse the username part of the common name and isolate the username. Follow up with

```
| tr '\n' , | sed -e 's/,$/\n/'
```

to convert the one-per-line username format into comma-separated form.

Comment: It would appear that the quotation marks (") were throwing off the regular expression.  Maybe something related to how awk outputs the substring.  Either way, removing the quotation mark in the sed statement, changing it to read `sed -e 's/^[^,]* \([^ ,]*\),.*/\1/'` works perfectly.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one quick and dirty way of doing it -

```
awk -v FS="[\"=,]" '{ print $3}' file | awk -v ORS="," '{print $NF}' | sed 's/,$//'
```

**Test:**

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat ff
"cn=Doe Jr. John john.doe,ou=...".
"cn=Doe A. Jane jane.a.doe,ou=...".
"cn=Smith Bob J bsmith,ou=...".
"cn=Powers Richard richard.powers1,ou=...".
[jaypal:~/Temp] awk -v FS="[\"=,]" '{ print $3}' ff | awk -v ORS="," '{print $NF}' | sed 's/,$//'
john.doe,jane.a.doe,bsmith,richard.powers1
```

**OR**

If you have `gawk` then

```
gawk '{ print gensub(/.* (.*[^,]),.*/,"\\1","$0")}' filename | sed ':a;{N;s/\n/,/}; ba'
```

**Test:**

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] gawk '{ print gensub(/.* (.*[^,]),.*/,"\\1","$0")}' ff | sed ':a;{N;s/\n/,/}; ba'
john.doe,jane.a.doe,bsmith,richard.powers1
```

Answer (score 0):

Given a file "Document1.txt" containing

cn=Smith Jane batty.cow,ou=ou1_value,ou=oun_value,o=o_value,c=c_value

cn=Marley Bob reggae.boy,ou=ou1_value,ou=oun_value,o=o_value,c=c_value

cn=Clinton J Bill ex.president,ou=ou1_value,ou=oun_value,o=o_value,c=c_value

you can do a

```
cat Document1.txt | sed -e "s/^cn=.* \([A-Za-z0-9._]*\),ou=.*/\1/p"
```

which gets you

batty.cow

reggae.boy

ex.president

using tr to transalate the end of line character

```
cat Document1.txt | sed -n "s/^cn=.* \([A-Za-z0-9._]*\),ou=.*/\1/p" | tr '\n' ','
```

produces

batty.cow,reggae.boy,ex.president,

you will need to deal with the last comma

but if you want it in a database say oracle for example, a script containing:

```
#!/bin/bash
doc=$1
cat ${doc} | sed -e "s/^cn=.* \([A-Za-z0-9._]*\),ou=.*/\1/p" | while read username
    do
    sqlplus -s username/password@instance <<+++ insert into mytable (user_name) values ('${username}'\;)
    exit
    +++
done
```

N.B.
The  A-Za-z0-9._ in the sed expression is every type of character you expect in the username - you may need to play with that one.

caveat - I did't test the last bit with the database insert in it!

Answer (score 0):

Perl regex solution that I consider more readable than the alternatives, in case you're interested:

```
perl -ne 'print "$1," if /(([[:alnum:]]|[[:punct:]])+),ou/' input.txt
```

Prints the string preceding 'ou', accepts alphanumeric and punctuation chars (but no spaces, so it stops at the username).

Output:

```
john.doe,jane.a.doe,bsmith,
```

Comment: There is a trailing `,` and the last name is skipped because it has number in it.

Comment: I fixed the number issue (alnum instead of alpha).

Answer (score 0):

It has been over a year since there has been an idea posted to this, but wanted a place to refer to in the future when this class of question comes up again.  Also, I did not see a similar answer posted.

Of the pattern of data provided, my interpretation is that we can strip away everything after the first comma, leaving us with a true CN rather than a DN that starts with a CN.
In the CN, we strip everything before and including the last white space.
This will leave us with the username.

awk -F',' /^cn=/{print $1}' ldapfile | awk '{print $NF}' >> usernames

Passing your ldap file to awk, with the field separator set to comma, and the match string set to cn= at the beginning of a line, we print everything up to the first comma.  Then we pipe that output into an awk with the default field separator and print only the last field, resulting in just the username. We redirect and append this to a file in the current directory named usernames, and we end up with one username per line.

To convert this into a single comma separated line of usernames, we change the last print command to printf, leaving out the \n newline character, but adding a comma.

awk -F',' /^cn=/{print $1}' ldapfile | awk '{printf $NF","}' >> usersnames

This leaves the only line in the file with a trailing comma, but since it is only intended to be used for cut and paste, simply do not cut the last character. :)